# PMDG 737-800 NGX Brakes Problem

Tags: flight-simulator-x

I use PMDG 737-800 NGX and have recently run into a problem that occurs on all my flights.

I us the autoland system, no problem, flare arms without rollout then I disengage autopilot, touch down, use reversers to 60kts, apply manual braking.
As far as I know, I haven't done anything wrong.

Then, as I come to about 30kts, the brakes stop working altogether including my parking brake; I just keep rolling. The only way I have been able to stop from this point onwards in about 10 flights is by using reversers again.

I've looked online and found no solution to this, please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'll probably get a better response over on [the avsim forums](http://forum.avsim.net/forum/432-pmdg-737ngx/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the autobrakes are disabled then. Should work.